# jQuery Selector by data attribute not working in Safari

Tags: jquery

The following show alert one and two in FF but just one in Safari. Is anything in this line incompatible in Safari? `if($('div[data-foo="'+bar+'"').hasClass('baz')){`

jQuery

```
alert('one');
if($('div[data-foo="'+bar+'"').hasClass('baz')){
    alert('two');
}else{
    alert('three');
}
```

HTML

```
<div data-foo="bar" class="baz"></div>
```

Answer (score 21):

You are missing a closing bracket ]. Also, bar is a string literal in this case, not a variable. This works:

```
alert('one');
if($('div[data-foo="bar"]').hasClass('baz')){
    alert('two');
}else{
    alert('three');
}
```

Or you can define bar as a variable:

```
var bar = "bar";
alert('one');
if($('div[data-foo="' + bar + '"]').hasClass('baz')){
    alert('two');
}else{
    alert('three');
}
```

(Not sure how it was otherwise working in Firefox before.)

Comment: I encountered a similar issue and it was because of the missing closing bracket "]". Mac Safari would throw an error while Windows-based browsers could identify the selector even with the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon what you want to really do where the alert statements are, you could make a shortcut with:

```
$('div.baz').each(function(){
  alert($(this).data('foo'));
});
```

This should create an alert stating `bar`